# The <el-dropdown> is experiencing an issue and cannot be used

Tags: javascript, vue.js

When I'm using Element-Plus, I noticed that when I import el-dropdown, it doesn't seem to be rendered as a functional dropdown menu.

Here is the code snippet I am using for it.

```
<template>
  <div>
    <el-dropdown>
    <span class="el-dropdown-link">
      Menu<i class="el-icon-arrow-down el-icon--right"></i>
    </span>
    <el-dropdown-menu slot="dropdown">
      <el-dropdown-item>黄金糕</el-dropdown-item>
      <el-dropdown-item>狮子头</el-dropdown-item>
      <el-dropdown-item>螺蛳粉</el-dropdown-item>
      <el-dropdown-item disabled>双皮奶</el-dropdown-item>
      <el-dropdown-item divided>蚵仔煎</el-dropdown-item>
    </el-dropdown-menu>
  </el-dropdown>
  </div>
</template>
```

And this is how it appears/rendered.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mmWjn.png)

When I hover over it, it only shows a black border, and the el-menu-item cannot be found within 'Elements'. What could be causing this? I haven't noticed any CSS affecting it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using incorrect [slot](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/slots.html#named-slots) syntax

```html
<el-dropdown-menu slot="dropdown">
 ...
</el-dropdown-menu>
```

Following the [Element Plus documentation](https://element-plus.org/en-US/component/dropdown.html#basic-usage) it should be:

```html
<template v-slot:dropdown>
  <el-dropdown-menu>
  ...
  </el-dropdown-menu>
</template>
```

Or using shorthand:

```html
<template #dropdown>
  <el-dropdown-menu>
  ...
  </el-dropdown-menu>
</template>
```

[codepen example](https://codepen.io/yoduh/pen/LYXPgYg?editors=1010)